# XPages checkboxgroup and default value

Tags: checkbox, xpages

As a follow up to my question on checkboxgroups, how does one set a default value?

Here's the source code for a test XPage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
<xp:checkBoxGroup id="checkBoxGroup1" defaultValue="First">
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="First" itemValue="1"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Second" itemValue="2"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Third" itemValue="3"></xp:selectItem>
</xp:checkBoxGroup>
</xp:view>
```

One would have expected the checkbox with the label "First" to be checked, but not so. Any insight into this would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dan,

Two things to try:

Easy Fix #1: Change default value to the itemValue. So this in the default value: `return "1";`

Easy Fix #2: Put code in beforePageLoad to set the default value to the data that it is bound to.  For example: If checkbox is bound a viewScope variable named "myCheckBox". Put code in the beforePageLoad to set `viewScope.myCheckBox = "1"`